# Labor Accountability

Tags: microsoft-excel

My goal is to return the total labor for each month by technician name.

I have a sheet called "MASTER DATA" which has

- "First name" in column E
- "Last name" in column F
- "Labor hours" in column G
- "service end dt" (month) in column L

I have another sheet called "First Last" on which I would like to create a summary table that has one row for each technician and one column for each month. The values in the table will be the sum of that technician's hours for that month.

I'm not sure if i should use a =VLOOKUP or =SUMIF formula to pull information from master data sheet to "first last" sheet cells B2:M2.

Comment: Either a SUMIF or a pivot table sounds like it would work, have you tried either?

Comment: I'm not familiar with how to make complex formulas work to be honest. I'm trying to teach myself via google/youtube as well as this site. I'll have to look up info on pivot tables. I did read more on SUMIF and it sounds like it may be able to do what i want, i just have to understand what data i need to input where within the formula.

Comment: What version do you have? Excel 2010 has a nice GUI to guide you through the formula process. It tells you exactly what cells to select.

Comment: Did you try the PivotTable?

Answer (score 1):

*This solves the issue:*

[image]

**How it works:**

- To get technicians unique list of names an array (CSE) formula in `First & Last` Sheet's cell F27:

  ```
  {=IFERROR(INDEX(Master!$A$27:$A$38, MATCH(0,COUNTIF($F$26:F26, Master!$A$27:$A$38), 0)),"")}
  ```

*Finish the formula with **Ctrl+Shift+Enter** & fill down.*

- Get work hour total for month formula in `First & Last` sheet'e cell G27:

  ```
  =SUMIFS(Master!$C$27:$C$44,Master!$A$27:$A$44,$F27,Master!$D$27:$D$44,G$26)
  ```
- *Fill the formula across.*
- *Additional formula to get Total works hours
  over the month in cell I27.*

  `=SUM(G27:H27)`

*You may adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*